# Using wsdl in pysimplesoap

Tags: python, wsdl, pysimplesoap

Not able to view debugged output and when tried with trace, gives an error:**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trace'

Answer (score 1):

Probably that is because you must be using ver 1.10. 

**Try**

 
a. comment out the line where you set trace = True or trace = False.
Trace has been probably removed in ver 1.10.

Or

b. revert back to version 1.05a